# How to resolve problem with update array of object?

Tags: reactjs

Main problem: I am fight against updating array of object in react big calendar. Problem is when I change position of one of object, all of them change start and end date like this one example.

I am pretty sure that this is because I wrote bad example of updating method of array of object

```
  const  resizeEvent = ({ event, start, end }) => {
      const nextEvents = allEvents.map(existingEvent => {
          if (existingEvent.id === event.id) {
            existingEvent.start = start;
            existingEvent.end = end;
        }
      
        return existingEvent;
          });
    
      setAllEvents(nextEvents)
  
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly the structure you have for `allEvents` and I guess you may want to copy the `existingEvent` before mutating ....

I mean something as below (commented about shallow copy)

```
const resizeEvent = ({ event, start, end }) => {
  const nextEvents = allEvents.map((event) => {
    const existingEvent = {... event};  // shallow copy to mutate
    if (existingEvent.id === event.id) {
      existingEvent.start = start;
      existingEvent.end = end;
    }
    return existingEvent;
  });
  setAllEvents(nextEvents);
};
```